# PPA for recent versions of mercurial

Tags: ppa, repository, mercurial

Im trying to access mercurial repositories that were created on windows with mercurial version 1.8.2. As the version in the repositories is a few numbers behind, its not playing ball. 
Does anyone know if there is a repository with up to date versions of mercurial or am i best just to build it from source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [add this ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to your sources:

```
 ppa:mercurial-ppa/stable-snapshots
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases** instead.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
```